# Can I remove jar from local repository without pom.xml?

Tags: java, maven, maven-dependency-plugin

I install my jar to local repository by command:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=aaa.jar -DgroupId=bbb -DartifactId=ccc -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

Now I want remove it from repository. I try command:

```
mvn dependency:purge-local-repository -DmanualInclude=bbb-ccc
```

But get error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:purge-local-repository (default-cli): Goal requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (...). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1]

Then I create `pom.xml` with data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project>
  <groupId>bbb</groupId>
  <artifactId>ccc</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <properties> 
    <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
    <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
    <packaging>${project.packaging}</packaging>
    <file>aaa.jar</file>
  </properties>     
</project>
```

Now I can remove jar from repository. But can I remove by command line without creating `pom.xml`?

I'm using 3.2.5 (windows x64).

Comment: As i know you can not remove files from repository by command line. But you can do it manually by deleting it from the m2 repository

Comment: Yes, I know about this way - home folder \ .m2 \ repository \ bbb \ ccc. But seems not "true" way :-( ...

Comment: There is no "true" way. Why you would like to remove something from repository?

Comment: Of couse, no need remove jar. We always can install again new jar with same version or install jar with other version. Hard to anwser...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [`dependency:purge-local-repository`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/purge-local-repository-mojo.html) goal, up to the current version 2.10, needs to be executed on a Maven project:

> Requires a Maven project to be executed.

One of the purpose of this goal is to remove from the local repository the dependencies of a Maven project, so it needs one to execute. This explains the error you have.

However, with this plugin, it is possible to specify a [`manualInclude`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/purge-local-repository-mojo.html#manualInclude) parameter, which will remove any dependency specified as `groupId:artifactId:version` or all versions of `groupId:artifactId` or even everything under a `groupId`. Therefore, the plugin could be updated to not require a Maven project to be executed.

I went ahead, created the JIRA issue [MDEP-537](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MDEP-537) to track this addition and will fix this for version 3.0.0.

Answer (score 1):

As [Tunaki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1743880/tunaki) mentioned in his answer, he requested MDEP-537 for the Dependency plugin to be able to purge without a Maven project. This has been implemented since version `3.0.0`.

If you only run `mvn dependency:purge-local-repository`, you are likely to **run an older version**. E. g. my Maven `3.6.0` comes with Dependency plugin version `2.8.0`.

So you should **run a specific version of the plugin**:

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.0.0:purge-local-repository -DmanualInclude=...
```